# Collapsing a grid column is not working programatically

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developing an UI for Raspberry PI using Universal Windows Application WPF.

I have to columns:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="400"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid Column="0" name="Column0">
  ...
</Grid>

<Grid Column="1" name="Column1">
  ...
</Grid>
```

and I have a button which do some stuff and after finish the operation, I want to hide first column and second one I want to fill to entire window.

I did this:

```
  private async void DisplaySomething_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
  {
     if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( City.Text ) ) {
        return;
     }

     // do some stuff

     Column0.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
     Column1.Width = MyPage.ActualWidth;
  }
```

But apparently the second column doesn't fit automatically to entire windows width. It preserve same width even first column is collapsed and second one  has `*` column width

Why ? Where's my mistake ?

Comment: Since `Column1` has a `*` width, you shouldn't set it to `MyPage.ActualWidth`, once you collapse `Column0` it should just fill all the Grid's space

Comment: Also, `<Grid Column="X" ...` should be `<Grid Grid.Column="X" ...`

Comment: Doesn't exists `Grid.Column` , exists only `<Grid Column="0" name="Column0">`

Answer (score 0):

> `<ColumnDefinition Width="400"></ColumnDefinition>`

The first column is not collapsed because it still has the `Width` set to 400. You have to set its `Width` to 0 when you are collapsing the content of the first column so the second column will be automatically expanded to full width.

Also as @Mogzol said, you should use the attached property `Grid.Column` when setting in which column the control will be displayed.

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CD_Column0" Width="400"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CD_Column1" Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="Gr_Column0" Grid.Column="0">
        ...
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="Gr_Column1" Grid.Column="1">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**C#:**

```
private async void DisplaySomething_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( City.Text ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // do some stuff

    Gr_Column0.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    CD_Column0.Width = new GridLength(0);
}
```